# Format large number output in Python's tqdm module for readability

Tags: python, python-3.x, progress-bar, tqdm

is there any way we can format a big number in tqdm's progress bar for better readability? For example, 1000000row/s must be 1,000,000rows/s .

I know about unit scale, but it formats a number like 1,21M rows/s which is not currently what I am trying to achieve

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of reverse-engineering [how tqdm handles it](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blob/4c956c20b83be4312460fc0c4812eeb3fef5e7df/tqdm/std.py#L566):

```py
from time import sleep

from tqdm import tqdm

tqdm.format_sizeof = lambda x, divisor=None: f"{x:,}" if divisor else f"{x:5.2f}"

with tqdm(total=1_000_000, unit_scale=True) as t:
    for _ in range(1_000_000):
        sleep(0.00001)
        t.update()
```

Prints:

```
  8%|████████████▊                     | 78,888/1,000,000 [00:04<00:56,  0.00it/s]
```

Comment: Works like charm! Thank you very much! However it does not show it/s - it's always zero. Its not a problem at all, but maybe there is a way it could be fixed?